# What to do with failed jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

In Google Cloud ML (Machine Learning), I submitted a job, but it failed due to a Python error in the code.

After fixing the error, how can I re-run the job? Should I submit a new job?

When I'm done, how to delete the job?

The online documentation is not complete.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you're ready to re-try the job, just submit a new job with a new job name.

There is no way to delete jobs since we want to provide you with a record of previous jobs. Jobs will reach a terminal state (FAILED, SUCCEEDED, or CANCELLED) in which they are no longer consuming any resources. However, the jobs will continue to show up in the UI or in the API if you list jobs.

Comment: Thank you. So, I'm gonna have lots of jobs listed there. After fixing each code error, I submit a new job.

Comment: @Androidification I am also facing the same issue and found no way to clear the failed jobs. Even the logs are linked to it. #Google could be troubled if someone prints junk logs just filling up server space.

Comment: Job logs are stored in StackDriver logging and will be retained in accordance with [StackDriver logging retention](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods)